# Installed polymode from Melpa, but everything comes up in Fundamental mode

Tags: r, polymode

I've been happily using polymode to edit Rmarkdown documents for many years. I had installed it and configured it manually, and it was fine until the sysadmins upgraded emacs from 24 to 27. The file I had installed manually in 2015 failed, so I figured I should update the package. I installed polymode, poly-R, etc. from Melpa. Everything seemed OK, but when I open a Rmd document I get no errors but it comes up in Fundamental mode. I have spent days searching for config advice but still no luck. Here is my .emacs file:

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(package-initialize)

(load "ess-autoloads")
(require 'ess-r-mode)

(let ((default-directory "~/.emacs.d/elpa"))
  (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
(setq package-check-signature nil)
(setq use-package-verbose nil)
(setq package-enable-at-startup t)
(setq package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize t)

;;; Markdown mode
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.markdown" . markdown-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.md" . markdown-mode) auto-mode-alist))

(require 'poly-R)
(require 'poly-markdown)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.md" . poly-markdown-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rmd" . poly-markdown-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rmd" . poly-markdown+poly-R
```

Oh, I just noticed that there's an error in my `.emacs` file. On startup it says this:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/home/me/.emacs’:
Wrong type argument: listp, melpa
```

I searched but couldn't find explanation for this. Is this why polymode doesn't work? Can anyone help, please?

Comment: I'm assuming you actually *do* have the missing `))` at the very end of that config, and there was a copy/paste error putting it into your question?

Comment: You've also added *two* `auto-mode-alist` entries for `"\\.Rmd"` but only the last one you add will have any effect.  And if you mean for all of your `auto-mode-alist` patterns to match *only* at the end of a filename, they should all finish with `\\'`.  E.g. `"\\.Rmd\\'"` and similarly for all the others.

Comment: Also, check that those values are correct.  I tried installing the packages, and I don't see any function named `poly-markdown+poly-R`, so that line might be more broken than only the missing `))`.  Maybe the function used to exist in the old version you had installed.  Check the package documentation for up to date instructions.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong/broken:

```el
(setq package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
```

`package-archives` is expected to be an alist so that structure is invalid (hence the error); and you almost certainly *don't* want to be clobbering the default list items by overwriting the entire list.

Change that line to this:

```el
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
```

Then restart Emacs.

---

You have other inconsistencies in that config as well.  As you've upgraded to Emacs 27, there are some start-up changes you want to be aware of -- [read in the NEWS file](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/NEWS.27#n212) about `early-init.el` and the `package-initialize` changes (type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> to read it inside Emacs).

I would *think* you can reduce everything from the start down to the `;;; Markdown mode` comment to just the following.  I've commented the `package-check-signature` line as I'm *assuming* you won't need that any more, but maybe I'm wrong about that.

```el
(load "ess-autoloads")
(require 'ess-r-mode)
;; (setq package-check-signature nil)
(setq use-package-verbose nil)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
```

Comment: This fixed the "wrong type argument" error message. Thanks!.  But I still can't get polymode to start when I load an Rmd file. Now when I start emacs I get this error when loading .emacs:
```
 Invalid slot name: #<pm-polymode latex-root>, :lighter`
``

Comment: I don't know, sorry -- that's clearly something specific to polymode (which I know nothing about).  Use `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and trigger the error and copy/paste the backtrace into your question.

Comment: I got this message:
`pm-polymode’s value is ‘pm-polymode’

  This variable is obsolete since 25.1;
  use \='pm-polymode instead

Documentation:
Polymode Configuration object.
Each polymode buffer holds a local variable ‘pm/polymode’
instantiated from this class or a subclass of this class.`

I'm pretty sure this is a package-internal thing, not under my control.

Comment: Again, you should edit the debug backtrace into your question if you're getting an actual error.  I cannot reproduce your issue after installing all those packages in Emacs 27.2 and visiting a new `foo.Rmd` file (notwithstanding my other comment that `poly-markdown+poly-R` does not appear to be a function at all, so I've omitted that line from the config).  Maybe you have simply not updated all of the packages which need updating.  See `C-h i g (emacs)Package Menu` regarding upgrading packages.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the names of the modes are as shown here:
[poly-R site](https://github.com/polymode/poly-R). Note that there is no second 'poly' in their names. You can see the available modes also from inside Emacs with 'M-x poly- '

I just installed poly-R version 20230416.1454 from 'melpa' and the modes worked even without me changing my .emacs. I had to invoke manually one of the modes on a suitable file first, but after that the the necessary modes were chosen automatically. I will update my .emacs anyway.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment, but nothing I could do would fix it. It works perfectly fine on 3 of my individual machines, but on the server nothing I can works. I'm just not going to use that machine anymore.